# Get object size from read_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, kaggle

I read a csv file and find the size of this

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
data.size
```

I got 10692 in result
But I try another way

```
y = data["Survived"]
```

This time, I only got 891 in length. As I think it must be 10692.
Would you like finding out the difference?
I downloaded data in here

https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data?select=train.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10692 is the total number of elements dataset contains.

It has 891 rows and 12 columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 891 entries, 0 to 890
Data columns (total 12 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   PassengerId  891 non-null    int64  
 1   Survived     891 non-null    int64  
 2   Pclass       891 non-null    int64
   .....
```

Answer (score 4):

It is expected, because [`DataFrame.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) working different, it counts all values of DataFrame.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'Survived':[7,8,9,4,2,3],

})

print (data)
   A  B  Survived
0  a  4         7
1  b  5         8
2  c  4         9
3  d  5         4
4  e  5         2
5  f  4         3

#3 columns x 6 rows = 18
print (data.size)
18

y = data["Survived"]
print (y)
0    7
1    8
2    9
3    4
4    2
5    3
Name: Survived, dtype: int64

#nuber of values in Series/column
print (y.size)
6
```

If want number of rows and columns:

```
print (data.shape)
(6, 3)
```

Or number of rows:

```
print (len(data))
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Moreover data.info() is an other way to get the shape information about your DataFrame. To get the exactly "size" in terms of memory usage just add the parameter memory_usage="deep".